# Tensor product of finite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I have seen various definitions for the tensor product $V \otimes W$ of two finite dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over some common field $F$. However, they all strike me as unnecessarily complicated. For a seemingly simpler definition, let's say $V$ is dimension $m$ and $W$ is dimension $n$. Then we know that $V \cong F^m$ and $W \cong F^n$. I know ahead of time that we sensibly want the dimension of $V \otimes W$ to be the product of the dimensions of $V$ and $W$, and we know that there is only one vector space over $F$ of any given dimension up to isomorphism, so why don't we first define $F^m \otimes F^n := F^{mn}$? Then, if we have an isomorphism from $V$ to $F^m$, and from $W$ to $F^n$, we can just 'pass through' $F^m \otimes F^n$, and use the (inverse) isomorphisms to then define $V \otimes W$? For instance, take $V$ to be polynomials in the variable $x$ of degree at most 2, and $W$ to be polynomials in variable $y$ of degree at most 1, with the standard bases, and with isomorphisms $a + bx + cx^2 \mapsto (a, b, c)$, and $s + ty \mapsto (s, t)$. Then $(a, b, c) \otimes (s, t) = (as, bs, cs, at, bt, ct)$ which then defines the map $(a + bx + cx^2) \otimes (s + ty) \mapsto (as \cdot 1 \otimes 1, bs \cdot x \otimes 1, cs \cdot x^2 \otimes 1, at \cdot 1 \otimes y, bt \cdot x \otimes y, ct \cdot x^2 \otimes y)$, where $1 \otimes 1, x \otimes 1, \dots, x^2 \otimes y$ are just symbols.

I am aware there is apparently some subtlety regarding the existence of the tensor product, and the usual way of constructing it is to perform some complicated quotient of vector spaces. Why do we bother going through this, if we know at the end the vector space needs to be isomorphic to $F^{mn}$ if it is going to exist at all? Is there some extra structure in tensor products that is not found in $F^{mn}$? I.e. is $V \otimes W$ 'more' than just a vector space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of extra structure, there is a bilinear map $V\times W \to V\otimes W$.  However, if $F^n$ has basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ and $F^m$ has basis $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ then you can just take the standard basis of $F^{mn}$ and label the basis elements $g_{ij}$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $j=1,\dots,m$.

Then you can define the bilinear map to send $(e_i,f_j)\mapsto g_{ij}$.

So what you describe is in practice the same as the standard construction.

One objection someone might raise to yours is that it involves picking a basis for your vector spaces (that is you need isomorphisms $V\cong F^n, \,W\cong F^m$).  You therefore need to show that these choices do not effect the result.

Again this is easy to fix: just show that your construction satisfies the universal property, and then any pair of sets of choices will lead to naturally isomorphic results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One issue I am still unsure about is the universal property you mention. If I understand it correctly, this defines the uniqueness of the pair $(V\otimes W, \otimes : V \times W \rightarrow V \otimes W)$ up to isomorphism. That is, if $V \otimes_1 W$ and $V \otimes_2 W$ are two tensor products of $V$ and $W$, then they must be isomorphic. So what I would want to show is that if I were to choose a different basis of $F^m$ and $F^n$, then applying the construction again would yield a new tensor product space that is isomorphic to the original?

Comment: Yes exactly.  If $V\otimes_1 W$ satisfies the universal property, then we have a map $V\otimes_1 W\to V\otimes_2 W$.  Similarly if $V\otimes_2 W$ satisfies the universal property, then we have a map $V\otimes_2 W\to V\otimes_1 W$.  Composing either way gives us the identity, so they are a pair of mutually inverse isomorphisms.  Thus all you need to do is show that whatever basis' you pick, the universal property is always satisfied, and you get the isomorphisms for free.  For clarity, the universal property of a tensor product is that for any bilinear map $V\times W \to U$, there is a unique

Comment: linear map $V\otimes W\to U$, so that the bilinear map is just the composition of the bilinear map $V\times W \to V\otimes W$, with the linear map.

Comment: Ok, so there's no need to actually show that a second choice of basis would also generate an isomorphic tensor product then, right? In principle, we could show that they would, but the fact that it would can be seen more abstractly from the universal property, plus the fact that the first construction indeed satisfies the universal property. So we really need "construction + universal property" in order to define tensor product. But what then is the purpose of the 'quotient construction' of tensor product? Does this only become more relevant in more general contexts?

Comment: Every vector space has a basis, so your construction would work for any vector space.  I think it is largely a matter of taste which you prefer, and which more obviously satisfies the universal property for you.  You are right - if we consider more general structures - like Hilbert spaces, then the tensor product will not be constructed in your way from vector space basis', though you could probably do something similar with Hilbert space basis' and complete in some way (I am not the right person to ask about that though).

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for the help!